# Confusion Decoding Using Format and Printf

Tags: java

I am very new to String formatting using format() and printf methods. I have read the tutorial on Oracle site but finding it very confusing. So decided to try some examples. I got this sample  and
have understood the output as `124.00`

```
public class TestStringFormatter {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    /* I do understand % - denotes start of instruction
       , is the flag
       6 - denotes width
       2 - Denotes precision
       f - Type */  
    String s = String.format("%,6.2f",124.000) ;
    System.out.printf(s);
  }
}
```

What i am not able to understand is , is the flag and how it is used in this formatting?
Can someone explain the use of flag "," in this example.

Comment: Hi Jim, its not about the documentation. I am going through it obviously, i am very new to it, i am confused about the output. Why didn't , get used in this, i thought the output should have been 124,00 something like that.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  I misread the question.  The answer is that you have not specified a locale in which the comma is used for decimal separator.  The comma in the format specification merely tells the formatter to use _the appropriate separators for the locale being used_.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jim, i understood it now. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma flag indicates that commas will be used to separate thousands, at least in the US. In other countries, it will use separators that make more sense in those countries. For example, formatting `123` with the comma flag will yield `123`, and formatting `123456789` with the comma flag will yield `123,456,789`.

Comment: hi @tbodt, what i don't get is why didn't , was used in this example. Why didn't it produce the output as 124,00.

Comment: That's becuase java doesn't think you are living in Germany or one of the other countries where decimal points are printed as commas.

Comment: Thanks tbodt. I understand it now. I need to explore it a little more in detail and do some more practice so that i can get comfortable with this.

Comment: :) I just did. I am waiting for the acceptance of the answer because it says i have to wait 2-3 minutes for this.